# How to start an FFmpeg process, create a pipe and write data from the parent process?

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, subprocess, pipe

My code is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279430/5941827.

I run FFmpeg with the following params:

```
std::stringstream sstm;
sstm << "ffmpeg -loglevel error -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s " << std::to_string(width) << "x" << std::to_string(height) //
        << " -pix_fmt rgb24 -framerate " << std::to_string(fps) << " -i - -c:v libx264 -preset " << getPreset(encodeSpeed) << //
        " -crf " << std::to_string(crf) << " -shortest " << path;
```

(the variables are initialized in a class constructor correctly)

Then I open the pipe with `pPipe = popen(sstm.str().c_str(), "w")`.The problem is after I `fwrite` to it and calling `fclose`, based on the contents I write sometimes less or more bytes reach FFmpeg, and I get

```
[rawvideo @ 000000000010c3df] Invalid buffer size, packet size 196606 < expected frame_size 196608
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
```

The saved output video usually has one frame more or less than the expected.
I have checked the array I'm sending trough the pipe with `fwrite` and it's size is correct.
It appears that based on the data I send some bytes don't get there, or more bytes than I send go through the pipe.

I have also tried two different FFmpeg versions, but with the same error message.

Comment: Writing binary data in text mode on windows?

Comment: @spectras Yes, I have a uint8_t array, that I fwrite to the ffmpeg pipe. Is there a way to have a pipe that receives raw data not just text?

Comment: hmmm, might check this, could do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924365/windows-pipes-in-binary-mode

Comment: @spectras Wow it works, thank you!!! I have added the line `_setmode(_fileno(pPipe), _O_BINARY);` after opening the pipe.